# SQL avg of comma occurrencies with condition

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I have a table of events where partecipants are listed as a comma separated list of IDs:

0,4,21,33,41

I'm trying to perform the following query to retrieve the average partecipants number for event only when status is equal to 1.

I prepared the following but doesn't work, anyone can help me?

```
SELECT avg(case when (status = 1 then LENGTH(REPLACE(listofPartecipants, ',', '')) end) avgPartecipants FROM events;
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expression if you want to count the number of elements in a list:

```
SELECT avg(case when status = 1
                then LENGTH(REPLACE(listofPartecipants, ',', 'XX')) - length(listofPartecipants) + 1
           end) as avgPartecipants
FROM events;
```

More important than getting this arcane string logic right is fixing your data model.  You should not be storing list of ids in a comma-delimited list.  You should have a table with one row per event and per participant.